# Logic App trigger not firing when Adding or Removing Parent Link

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I have created 2 triggers -

1. Insert
2. Update

When i create a new work item without adding parent link then trigger gets called perfectly.
Now, When i update the same work item by adding a parent link work item, Update trigger is not getting called.

Update Case - When i add a parent link work item and also change the title or description then trigger gets called.

So what i wanna achieve is to call update trigger during adding or removing parent link also.

Please find Insert and Update trigger Screen shots - 
[Insert Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqp0c.png)
[Update Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe9mA.png)

These triggers gets fired whenever any write operation gets performed i.e while creating work item or updating work item.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide more details of your logic app such as screenshots ? And may I know what does "insert trigger" and "update trigger" mean ?

Comment: you can check now. I have added screenshots of triggers.